# I can't render cyan part of anaglyph

Tags: rendering, stereoscopy

I run v2.78
When I'm rendering my animation, only the red part renders.
I have everything set in Output (render) and Stereoscopy (Camera settings) but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Can you add some screeshoots to your  post, because I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Could you have accidentally pressed the *Red Channel* button on the image viewer window?